# How can I build required parameters with Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am having base URL for example

```
  let url = "http://localhost:5000";
```

I want to dynamically append some `required URL parameters` to this URL

But when I try

```
    var url = new URL(this.url);
    url.searchParams.set('application', 'ib');
    url.searchParams.set('id', '12345');
    console.log('url', url.href);
```

i get

http://localhost:5000/?application=ib&id=12345

but I need to get `required params` all the time, not first query param and after that params splitted with `&`

http://localhost:5000/application=ib&id=12345

Is there a way to automatically remove the ?

I know that I can make some kind of modifying the string but
Is there some js method for this To get all the time directly required params?

Comment: I don't think that's valid URL syntax. If there's a query string, it has to be separated by `?`.

Comment: You can't. A search param is, by definition, part of the search query that is inserted after the `?` in a URL. This feels like an XY problem: what are you trying to achieve here? Why is your server not parsing the original URL you get correctly?

Comment: This is not a "required parameter", it's parameters passed in the [path of the URL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL) - very weird, and should not contain a `&` character. There is no native method to build such non-standard URLs. Why does your server not accept parameter through the [query string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string)?

Comment: Url parameters **must** be separated with an `?` after the URL.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is more that you are using `.searchParams()`, which means query and queries are always indicated by the `?` part of a URL.
If you want to change the base URL, why not do that?

**Set URL by changing `URL.href`**

```js
let baseUrl = "http://localhost:5000";
let applicationName = 'ib';
let applicationId = '12345';

url = new URL(baseUrl);
url.href += 'application/' + applicationName;
url.href += '/id/' + applicationId;
console.log(url.href); // http://localhost:5000/application/ib/id/12345

// again the alternative URL if "application" and "id" is implied in your URL:
url = new URL(baseUrl);
url.href += applicationName;
url.href += '/' + applicationId;
console.log(url.href); // http://localhost:5000/ib/12345"
```